# OSGI - Split entities in multiple bundles

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, apache-karaf

I am making an osgi application running on karaf 4.0.4.

My application use a single PostgreSQL database. 
The connector is handled by pax-jdbc.
I use Karaf `JPA 2.3.0` feature and `Hibernate 4.3.6.Final` feature.

Some modules offers services that can be added/removed.

TL/DR: **Is there anyway to split my entities in multiple bundles?**

Here is my situation:

I currently have a module named `model` that hold

- my `persistence.xml` file
- classes annotated `@Entity`
- classes annotated `@Entity` and `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`
- services to access my entites.

Here is my persistence file:

```
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="maindb" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=maindb)</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And the abstract service that is subclassed to access those entities:

```
public abstract class AbstractDaoService<T> implements IDaoService<T> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "maindb")
    protected EntityManager entitymanager;

    protected Class<T> clazz;

    public AbstractDaoService(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public T find(Object id) {
        return entitymanager.find(clazz, id);
    }

    // rest of class is omitted
}
```

Now, I have 3 other bundles. let's call them A, B and C. A use entities from `model` through services inject by blueprint. This works fine.

But the problem is that A also use services provided by B and C. And in each of those 2 bundles, there is class annotated `@Entity` and class extending extending the ones with the `@Inheritance` annotation.

- At first, I just tried to basically add those bundles and run it. The entityManager could be found in `B` and `C`.
- Next attemp is to add a `persistence.xml`file in each of my bundles but it doesn't works as scheme in `A` is seen as different and it won't load the extending class from `B` and `C`
- Then I tried to split `B` in half: one (B-Main) with the services I wanted to implement, and the other (B-frag) as a bundle-fragment hosted by `model`. Same thing for bundle `C`. 
  Installing `model`, `A`, and just `B-Main`and `B-frag` (or `C-Main`and `C-frag`) works fine. But if I try to install `B-Main`,`B-frag`,`C-Main`and `C-frag`, I get the following error:

.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: maindb] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping <my class annotated with @Inheritance`>
```

I think it happens because when the second fragment is resolved, it reload the host fragment and try to remap the entities on the already existing entitymanager (not sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OSGi spec  4.2 127.3.2 defines the Persistence Bundle. It contains one or more persistence units. All entities defined in the persistence unit must originate in the bundle´s jar. They may not come from a fragment.

I think you can theoretically put entity classes in another bundle but only if the persistence bundle imports these packages. So you can not use this to extend classes later in the way that the main persistence bundle does not know them.

Comment: it's too bad it can't be extended, in my opinion, that's a big loss for modularity. What if I have other entities unrelated to the ones in my persistence bundle? Can I have multiple persistence bundles with unrelated entities with a similar `persitence.xml` file ?

Comment: You can have several persistence units but they will be unrlelated on the database. I think extending would not work in practice anyway as bundles come and go but the database will always be the same.